# Folder access PHP on dedicated server

Tags: php

Can I access a folder on a different account on the same dedicated server via PHP?

Comment: Yes, Sure If user have permission to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably all the folders in the server are in ***/home/_folder_you_want_*** (if the host uses linux), and so you can define a constant define('HOME', '/home/'), and include (like: include( HOME . '*folder*');) the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of factors to consider but the answer would be yes if you have permissions.